# Geolocation doesn't update my walked distance

Tags: javascript, geolocation

Hi I'm creating an walk tracker webapp by usiing geolocation with javascript. Everything works fine except the part when I have to calculate the distance by using the old latlong with new latlong.

The Code:

```
function updateLocation(position) {
   var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
   var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
   var accuracy = position.coords.accuracy;
   var timestamp = position.timestamp;

   document.getElementById("latitude").innerHTML = latitude;
   document.getElementById("longitude").innerHTML = longitude;
   document.getElementById("accuracy").innerHTML = accuracy.toFixed(2) + " meter";
   document.getElementById("timestamp").innerHTML = new Date(timestamp).toLocaleString();


   if (accuracy >= 500) {
     updateStatus("Need more accurate values to calculate distance.");
     return;
   }

   if ((lastLat != null) && (lastLong != null)) {
     var currentDistance = distance(latitude, longitude, lastLat, lastLong);
     document.getElementById("currDist").innerHTML =
       "Current distance traveled: " + currentDistance.toFixed(2) + " km";

     totalDistance += currentDistance;

     document.getElementById("totalDist").innerHTML =
       "Total distance traveled: " + currentDistance.toFixed(2) + " km";
   }


   lastLat = latitude;
   lastLong = longitude;

   updateStatus("Location successfully updated.");
}
```

Added the distance function*

```
Number.prototype.toRadians = function() {
return this * Math.PI / 180;
```

}

```
function distance(latitude1, longitude1, latitude2, longitude2) {
// R is the radius of the earth in kilometers
var R = 6371;

var deltaLatitude = (latitude2-latitude1).toRadians();
var deltaLongitude = (longitude2-longitude1).toRadians();
latitude1 = latitude1.toRadians(), latitude2 = latitude2.toRadians();

var a = Math.sin(deltaLatitude/2) *
        Math.sin(deltaLatitude/2) +
        Math.cos(latitude1) *
        Math.cos(latitude2) *
        Math.sin(deltaLongitude/2) *
        Math.sin(deltaLongitude/2);

var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a),
                       Math.sqrt(1-a));
var d = R * c;
return d;
```

}

Hope someone can find what Im doing wrong.
Thank you

**Update:**

I found the problem why geolocation didn't update my distance.. it's because the variable **lastlong** and **lastlat** which I declared didn't gave me the previous location, it gave me the current location of **latitude** and **longitude** which I declared inside updateLocation and assign lastlat and last long with those variable.

*My question is now how can I calculate the previous location with the
new location, can't find any solution for it.*

**New Update:**

> Found my solution for this problem. For calculating the previous
>   distance I store the coords in a array and get the last position to
>   calculate the distance with the current position.

**Code:**

```
 var coords = []; var distance = 0.0;



function calculateDistance(fromPos, toPos) {
    var radius = 6371;
    var toRad = function(number) {
        return number * Math.PI / 180;
    };

    var latDistance = toRad(toPos.latitude - fromPos.latitude);
    var lonDistance = toRad(toPos.longitude - fromPos.longitude);
    var a = Math.sin(latDistance / 2) * Math.sin(latDistance / 2) + 
            Math.cos(toRad(fromPos.latitude)) * Math.cos(toRad(toPos.latitude)) * 
            Math.sin(lonDistance / 2) * Math.sin(lonDistance / 2);

    return radius * (2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a))); 
}


var lastPos = coords[coords.length-1];
    if(lastPos) {

        distance += calculateDistance(lastPos, position.coords);
        document.getElementById("currDist").innerHTML =
    "Current distance traveled: " + distance.toFixed(2) + " km";
    }


    coords.push(position.coords);
```

One thing that I not understand is why my timestamp inside my array is undefined? Because the lat and long can I get easy without problem.

Comment: Where is the "distance" function?

Comment: @McMurphy, the distance function is just the haversinformula

Comment: Does it comeback with 0 each time? NaN? undefined? 23?

Comment: Yes indeed! The travelled distance always resets itself to 0.0km

Comment: Don't update Last lat/lng unless distance is > 0 and initialize last lat/lng first time

Comment: Thanks for the provided link but I found a easier solution :)

Answer (score 0):

For a complete working journey logger example please see [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B7Rmd3Rn8_hDNW1zSWRoXzBTclU) or [GitHub](https://github.com/RichardMaher/Brotkrumen).

Pay attention to the filterLocation function in TravelManagerPolyfil.js as you might just be getting many zero distance readings and need to throttle watchPosition.

This code works: -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to get your coordinates.</p>

<button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
    var perthLat = 31.9505;
    var perthLon = 115.8605;
    var freoLat = 32.0569;
    var freoLon = 115.7439;
    const EARTH_RADIUS = 6378137; 
    var toRad = 
        function (num) {
            return num * Math.PI / 180;
        };  
    var calculateDistance =
        function(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2){
            var dLat = toRad(lat2 - lat1);
            var dLon = toRad(lon2 - lon1);
            var a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) + Math.cos(this.toRad(lat1)) * 
                    Math.cos(toRad(lat2)) * Math.sin(dLon / 2) * Math.sin(dLon / 2);
            var distance = EARTH_RADIUS * 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
            return distance;
        }

var x = document.getElementById("demo");

function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else { 
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}

function showPosition(position) {
    x.innerHTML = "Distance = " + 
        calculateDistance(perthLat, perthLon,
                          freoLat, freoLon) / 1000;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi McMurphy the code still not worked for me.. im using ur code as follows: var currentDistance = this.calculateDistance(latitude, longitude, lastLat, lastLong);  do I miss some library for using the tier3toolbox?

Comment: Can you provide the 4 values you are using to test? Have you step through with debug?

Comment: You can see my values in my example above. No Im just using notepad++

Comment: @anonymous Look, not sure what you're doing but I edited the answer to be a complete working example of calculating the distance between Perth and Fremantle. The answer is just over 16km as the crow flies

Comment: Thank you for your answer the code works good indeed but it only works with fixed latlong I want to track my distance live like how a running apps works.. tracking evey step you make.